# Initial few characters are getting truncated while decrypting

Tags: java, encryption

I'm very new in Java and trying to implement Java encryption/decryption for a text file. Here I can see some of the starting characters in line 1 is getting truncated while decrypting a encrypted file.

Below is my code. Please suggest if I'm missing anything.

```
package com.myprotection;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Crypto
{
    private String mPassword = null;
    byte [] mInitVec = null;
    byte [] mSalt = null;
    Cipher mEcipher = null;
    Cipher mDecipher = null;
    private final int KEYLEN_BITS = 256;
    private final int ITERATIONS = 65536;
    private final int MAX_FILE_BUF = 1024;


    public Crypto (String password, String hint) throws Exception
    {
        mPassword = password;
        mSalt = getSaltedByteFromString( hint );
    }


    public void WriteEncryptedFile (String input, String output) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream (new File(input));
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream (new File(output));
        int nread = 0;
        byte [] inbuf = new byte [MAX_FILE_BUF];

        //Initialize Encryption Vector
        initializeInitVec();

        while ((nread = fin.read (inbuf)) > 0 )
        {

            // create a buffer to write with the exact number of bytes read. Otherwise a short read fills inbuf with 0x0
            // and results in full blocks of MAX_FILE_BUF being written. 
            byte [] trimbuf = new byte [nread];
            for (int i = 0; i < nread; i++)
                trimbuf[i] = inbuf[i];

            // encrypt the buffer using the cipher obtained previosly
            byte [] tmp = mEcipher.update (trimbuf);

            // I don't think this should happen, but just in case..
            if (tmp != null)
                fout.write (tmp);
        }

        // finalize the encryption since we've done it in blocks of MAX_FILE_BUF
        byte [] finalbuf = mEcipher.doFinal ();
        if (finalbuf != null)
            fout.write (finalbuf);

        fout.flush();
        fin.close();
        fout.close();
        fout.close ();
    }


    public void ReadEncryptedFile (String input, String output) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream (new File(input));
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream (new File(output));
        CipherInputStream cin;
        int nread = 0;
        byte [] inbuf = new byte [MAX_FILE_BUF];

        //Initializing decrypting 
        setupDecrypt();

        // creating a decoding stream from the FileInputStream above using the cipher created from setupDecrypt()
        cin = new CipherInputStream (fin, mDecipher);

        while ((nread = cin.read (inbuf)) > 0 )
        {

            // create a buffer to write with the exact number of bytes read. Otherwise a short read fills inbuf with 0x0
            byte [] trimbuf = new byte [nread];
            for (int i = 0; i < nread; i++)
                trimbuf[i] = inbuf[i];

            // write out the size-adjusted buffer
            fout.write (trimbuf);
        }

        fout.flush();
        cin.close();
        fin.close ();       
        fout.close();
    }

    private void setupDecrypt () throws Exception {

        SecretKeyFactory factory = null;
        SecretKey tmp = null;
        SecretKey secret = null;

        //Get initialized the vector
        initializeInitVec();

        factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(mPassword.toCharArray (), mSalt, ITERATIONS, KEYLEN_BITS);
        tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        /* Decrypt the message, given derived key and initialization vector. */
        mDecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        mDecipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(mInitVec));
    }

    private void initializeInitVec() throws Exception {

        SecretKeyFactory factory = null;
        SecretKey tmp = null;

        factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec (mPassword.toCharArray (), mSalt, ITERATIONS, KEYLEN_BITS);
        tmp = factory.generateSecret (spec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec (tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        //Create the Encryption cipher object and store as a member variable
        mEcipher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        mEcipher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        AlgorithmParameters params = mEcipher.getParameters ();

        // get the initialization vectory and store as member var 
        mInitVec = params.getParameterSpec (IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    }

    private byte[] getSaltedByteFromString( String hintString ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(hintString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return md.digest();
    }
}
```

Testing of the above code:

```
public class TestCrypto {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String pwd = "Tipu";
        String hint = "My Dog Name";

        Crypto cpo = new Crypto(pwd, hint);
        cpo.WriteEncryptedFile("C:\\Users\\roul\\Desktop\\TestEncryption.txt", "C:\\Users\\roul\\Desktop\\en-TestEncryption.txt");
        cpo.ReadEncryptedFile("C:\\Users\\roul\\Desktop\\en-TestEncryption.txt", "C:\\Users\\roul\\Desktop\\de-TestEncryption.txt");


    }
}
```

Test Case File Content *TestEncryption.txt*:

> My Encryption testing
>   This is my test encryption.

encrypted **TestEncryption.txt**:

> fè"Ç2¨1.ñ|#¼Ê¯—Ã&ýnfK[ùn§Ù @ÛPzÎ•¯sö®õ˜ýóK8ÄÜ¨`‹¹*¢ÙF›Ã

decrypted *TestEncryption.txt*:

> ³‰XgÜOÂN‹¶ƒ×­N›sting
>   This is my test encryption.

Comment: Your code would be much more useful as a self-contained example. Add a `main` method and provide us with some test data: tell us a sample password and include a (small) encrypted file, expressed in hexadecimal, into your question.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't need trimbuf and that byte array copy if you simply used http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#update%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29

Comment: Code wise there are many issues related to error handling and other things but I'm concerned about the encryption and decryption logic. Please suggest if I'm making any mistake on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more errors here, but certainly one of them is your handling of IVs.

Every time you call `initializeInitVec()`, it stores a *random* IV in `mInitVec`. So you can't use that method as a way of retrieving the IV used in a previous encryption operation.

Unfortunately, your current code does exactly that. As a result, you are trying to decrypt with the wrong IV and presumably get a padding exception, which is swallowed up by the input stream.

To solve this, you must store the IV with the encrypted data. A common approach is to write your IV to your file, followed by your encrypted contents. For decryption, you must first read this IV and then decrypt the following contents.

Comment: I don't want to store the IV anywhere. Simply want to calculate that again. Is it possible??

Comment: @Mr.... Sure, but then it won't be semantically secure anymore if you use a static IV.

Comment: What you told it's correct! Just to know, how I'm able to decrypt almost all( except initial few characters) encrypted text with a different IV value?

Comment: @Mr.... [Take a look at how CBC decryption works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29). The IV only influences the first block of plaintext that is produced.